# Noun Synonyms in WordNet

Tags: elasticsearch, wordnet, synonym

I want to use the `synonym` tokenfilter in Elasticsearch for an index. I downloaded the Prolog version of WordNet 3.0, and found the `wn_s.pl` file that Elasticsearch can understand. However, it seems that the file contains synonyms for all sorts of words and phrases, while I am really only interested in supporting synonyms for nouns. Is there a way to extract those type of entries?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a computer that can tell if a word is a noun or not? Could you post some examples...

Comment: No, I am asking if there is a way to reduce the size of the file such that only nouns remain. For example, if I search `universe` (noun), results related to `cosmos` will be a part of the hits, but if I search `study` (verb), results that only have the word `learn` will not be a part of the hits.

Comment: a sample of the code you're using would help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that the format of `wn_s.pl` is

```
s(112947045,1,'usance',n,1,0).
s(200001742,1,'breathe',v,1,25).
```

A very raw way of doing that would be to execute the following in your terminal to only take the lines from that file that have the ',n,' string.

```
grep ",n," wn_s.pl > wn_s_nouns_only.pl
```

The file `wn_s_nouns_only.pl` will only have the entries that are marked as nouns.

Comment: Oh yeah! How did I not think of this. Thanks! You can also do `grep ",n," wn_s.pl > wn_s_nounsOnly.pl` as a slightly shorter version.